# Add offset to UTC time in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have time value as string. I also have a timezone offset value. How can I easily add this timezone value to the time?

```js
let time = "13:27"
timezoneOffset = "180"
let convertedTime="?";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let time = "13:27"
timezoneOffset = "180"

let parsedtimezoneOffset = parseInt(timezoneOffset)

let[hours,minutes] = time.split(':').map(e => parseInt(e))

let[offsetHours,offsetMinutes] = [parsedtimezoneOffset/60 - parsedtimezoneOffset % 60,parsedtimezoneOffset % 60]

let newTimeString = (hours + offsetHours) % 24 + ':' + (minutes + offsetMinutes) % 60

console.log(newTimeString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const time_string = "13:27";
const offset = "150" // minutes

const arr = time_string.split(":");
console.log(arr); // Output : > Array ["13", "27"]
const hh = parseInt(arr[0]);
const mm = parseInt(arr[1]);
const diff = parseInt(offset);

arr[0] = (hh + Math.floor(( mm + diff )/60  ))%24;
arr[1] = (mm + diff )%60;

const convertedTime = arr[0] + ":" + arr[1];
console.log(convertedTime);  //Output : "15:57"
```